# Update of Xcode command line is not installing

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update, big-sur

Even though I have agreed and downloaded the update it's not installing,
It is not even showing any error for not installing.

I am currently using macOS 11.2.3

Can any one please help me to solve this?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you click "update now", what happens if you click on "more info"?

Comment: When i click update now it downloading and installing and again showing that to update.

Comment: It was resolved after the shutdown of the system

Comment: @HarikrishnaGoli please post an answer

Comment: Do i have to add the answer like After the shutting down and restarting of the system the update promote is not coming?